# CherryPy get uploaded file's temporary location

Tags: python, cherrypy

File Uppload in CherryPy:

```
    def upload(self, myFile):
        out = """File name: %s, Content-Type: %"""
        return out % (myFile.filename, myFile.content_type)
    upload.exposed = True
```

From [docs](https://cherrypy.readthedocs.org/en/3.2.6/progguide/files/uploading.html):

> When a client uploads a file to a CherryPy application, it’s placed on
>   disk immediately. CherryPy will pass it to your exposed method as an
>   argument (see “myFile” below); that arg will have a “file” attribute,
>   which is a handle to the temporary uploaded file. If you wish to
>   permanently save the file, you need to read() from myFile.file and
>   write() somewhere else.

How can I get uploaded file's temporary location?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't get the name of the temporary file by using the default entity processor. But you can set you own custom one to ensue that a temporary file is always created (usually is not created for files <1000 bytes).

To have a name in the temporary file you need a `NamedTemporaryFile` which is created with the `CustomPart` class:

```
import tempfile
import cherrypy as cp

class App:

    @cp.expose
    def index(self):
        return """
        <html><body>
            <h2>Upload a file</h2>
            <form action="upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            filename: <input type="file" name="my_file" /><br />
            <input type="submit" />
            </form>
        </body></html>
        """

    @cp.expose
    def upload(self, my_file):
        return "The path is %s" % my_file.file.name


class CustomPart(cp._cpreqbody.Part):
    """
    Custom entity part that it will alway create a named
    temporary file for the entities.
    """
    maxrambytes = 0 # to ensure that it doesn't store it in memory

    def make_file(self):
        return tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    cp.quickstart(App(), config={
        '/': {
            'request.body.part_class': CustomPart
        }
    })
```

You would not be able to see the file when the request is done because by default the `NamedTemporaryFile` class deletes the file as soon as it closed. In this case as soon as the request finish. You can add some sleep calls like this and validate what I have just said:

```
   @cp.expose
   def upload(self, my_file):
        import time
        cp.log.error("You have 30 seconds to open the temporary file %s" % my_file.file.name)
        time.sleep(30)
        return "The path is %s" % my_file.file.name
```

If you really want to keep the temporary file then you just have to set the `delete` parameter to `False` on the `NamedTemporaryFile` and end up with something like this:

```
 class CustomPart(cp._cpreqbody.Part):
        """
        Custom entity part that it will alway create a named
        temporary file for the entities.
        """
        maxrambytes = 0 # to ensure that it doesn't store it in memory

        def make_file(self):
            return tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False)
```

You'll have to make sure that you delete those temporary files on your own.